# Difficulties choosing the right contours; e.g. $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{1+x^2} dx$, with $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $0<|a|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I'm often stuck at choosing the right contour to integrate along. Are there some general rules of thumb to choose a suitable one?

For example, I got stuck at this one:
$ \displaystyle
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{1+x^2} dx$
 with $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $0<|a|<1$

What would be the procedure to come up with a suitable contour?

Comment: Do you have any info regarding $\;a\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I've edited it. Is that crucial for choosing a contour?

Comment: Sort of. If you had $a = 0$, then you'd choose a different contour (or an entirely different method of evaluating the integral), and if $a \leqslant -1$ or $a \geqslant 1$, the integral wouldn't converge.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you illustrate me how you see that?

Comment: Near $0$, the integrand behaves like $x^a$, so for $a \leqslant -1$, you have a non-integrable singularity in $0$. Near $+\infty$, the integrand behaves like $x^{a-2}$, so if $a \geqslant 1$, the integral doesn't converge. [aside: you can allow complex $a$, then the restrictions are on $\operatorname{Re} a$]

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your explanation. Can you maybe also tell me how you would decide on the contour?

Comment: Thinking about how to tell. Usually, one knows some types of contour, and just looks which would work for the problem at hand. In this case, one would use a keyhole contour, but I'm still pondering how one can explain how to find that.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there are a couple of approaches that work.  Here, because the denominator just has an $x^2$, you can simply use a semicircle in the upper (or lower) half plane with a small semicircular notch cut out about the origin to avoid the branch point at the origin.  In this case, you would need to split the integral along the real axis up for negative and positive values of $x$.  The result is that $1-e^{i \pi a}$ times the integral is $i 2\pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=i$ for the contour in the upper half plane.

A contour that works for more general cases is a keyhole contour about the positive real axis.  In this case, $1-e^{i 2 \pi a}$ times the integral is $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at the poles $z= i$ and $z= -i$.  This contour works because it exploits the multivaluedness of the $x^a$ piece.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your second method is how I've been taught to do it for this particular integral. However, the general principle isn't clear to me. When someone would ask me a next integral, e.g. $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{1+x^4} dx$, what contour should I choose and why? Again, I would start exploiting the multivaluedness of $ \log z $ , but then my question pops up: which branch should I choose now and what is going to be my contour?

Comment: @user102815: it takes some experience to see the best contour to use.  On the surface, in this case, you could use a keyhole contour as you were taught and no problem.  The only thing is, you would have to evaluate the residues at all four poles, and you may wonder if you could do better.  Is there any symmetry to exploit?  In this case, yes!  You could do a semicircle like that above and compute two residues, or...you could do a quarter circle about the first quadrant with a quarter circle notch about the origin and compute only one residue.

Comment: Note that, for logs, you would consider the contour integral of $\ln^2{z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. I have however 2 questions on what you mention: 1: I see the symmetry, but how exactly would I exploit it? Can I ''ignore'' poles?   2: Your last comment is unclear to me though: why should I consider $\ln^2 z $?

Comment: @user102815: because when you subtract $\ln^2{z}$ and $(\ln{z}+i2 \pi)^2$, (or whatever phase term results from your contour) the terms involving $\ln^2{z}$ cancel and you will be left with the original integral involving $\ln{z}$.

Comment: Also, you do not ignore poles.  For poles inside your contour, the sum of the residues at those poles is the value of the contour integral.